Calling useFetch() in Nuxt 3 causes Vue Router error in Docker container
Unfortunately, I can’t trace under what circumstances this started.
But when I try to run it in Docker, errors appear in the console, and the application does not respond to requests.
Nuxt 3.10.2
Docker: 25.0.3
Essence:
Running the application on my host, npm run dev, the application works, there are no errors.
But if I run the application in a docker container, then all useFetch requests throw a Vue Router error:
> docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up
[+] Running 1/2нение пакетного файла [Y(да)/N(нет)]?
 ✔ Network frontend    Created                                                                                     0.1s
 - Container frontend  Created                                                                                     0.2s
Attaching to frontend
frontend  |
frontend  | > dev
frontend  | > nuxt dev
frontend  |
frontend  | Nuxt 3.10.2 with Nitro 2.8.1
frontend  |
frontend  | [QR code]
frontend  |
frontend  |   ➜ Local:    http://0.0.0.0:/
frontend  |   ➜ Network:  http://172.19.0.4:/ [QR code]
frontend  |   ➜ Network:  http://172.20.0.2:/
frontend  |
frontend  | [nuxt:tailwindcss] ℹ Using default Tailwind CSS file
frontend  | ℹ Compiled types/plugins.d.ts in 774.5ms
frontend  | ℹ Compiled plugins/server.mjs in 769.24ms
frontend  | ℹ Compiled plugins/client.mjs in 798.45ms
frontend  | ℹ Vite server warmed up in 76990ms
frontend  | ℹ Vite client warmed up in 82499ms
frontend  | [nitro] ✔ Nitro built in 4538 ms
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"
frontend  | [Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/user/profile"

Javascript
     //// file: ./plugins/loadCity.ts
    import {useCityStore} from "~/store/useCityStore";
    
    export default defineNuxtPlugin(async (nuxtApp) => {
        const location = useCityStore();
    
        if(!location.currentCity){
            await location.fetchCity(); // Error: No match found for location with path "/api/v1/city/get"
        }
    });
    
    
    
    
    //// file: /store/useCityStore.ts
    import { defineStore } from "pinia";
    
    export const useCityStore = defineStore('location', () => {
        async function fetchCity() {
            const {data} = await useApiFetch(`/api/v1/city/get`);
    
            // other code
        }
        return { fetchCity }
    });
    
    
    
    //// file: useApiFetch.ts
    export function useApiFetch<T> (path: string|(() => string)|ComputedRef<string>, options: UseFetchOptions<T> = {}) {
        const config = useRuntimeConfig()
    
        const xsrfToken = useCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');
    
        let headers: any = {
            accept: 'application/json',
            referer: config.public.api.referer,
            ...options?.headers,
        }
    
        if (xsrfToken && xsrfToken.value !== null) {
            headers['X-XSRF-TOKEN'] = xsrfToken.value as string;
        }
    
        if (process.server) {
            headers = {
                ...headers,
                ...useRequestHeaders(['cookie']),
            }
        }
    
        return useFetch(path, {
            baseURL: config.public.api.url,
            watch: false,
            credentials: 'include',
            ...options,
            headers,
        })
    }

Dockerfile
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1

ARG NODE_VERSION=20.9

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-slim as base

ENV NODE_ENV=development

WORKDIR /src

# Build
FROM base as build

COPY --link package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install

# Run
FROM base

COPY --from=build /src/node_modules /src/node_modules

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]

Docker compose yml:
version: '3.7'
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile.dev
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/src
      - node_modules:/src/node_modules
    working_dir: /src
    expose:
      - 80
      - 24678
    ports:
      - "24678:24678"
    environment:
      NODE_OPTIONS: '--max_old_space_size=4096'
      VIRTUAL_HOST: $FRONTEND_DOMAIN
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: $FRONTEND_DOMAIN
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: "le@bybuy.kz"
      HTTPS_METHOD: noredirect
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 80
      NITRO_PORT: 80
      NITRO_HOST: 0.0.0.0
      PORT: 80
      NUXT_SITE_URL: $NUXT_SITE_URL
      NUXT_API_URL: $NUXT_API_URL
      NUXT_API_REFERRER: $NUXT_API_REFERRER
      NUXT_SEARCH_API_KEY: $NUXT_SEARCH_API_KEY
      NUXT_SEARCH_HOST: $NUXT_SEARCH_HOST
      NUXT_SEARCH_PORT: $NUXT_SEARCH_PORT
      NUXT_SEARCH_PROTOCOL: $NUXT_SEARCH_PROTOCOL
    networks:
      - frontend
      - reverse-proxy

networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    name: reverse-proxy
    external: true
  frontend:
    name: frontend
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  node_modules:

There was an assumption that the problem was a proxy, and requests to the api were sent not to the backend, but to the nuxt application.
But if you just raise the container, without a proxy, and send an http request directly to the container, then the error repeats.
upd:When I start the container and the page does not open, Error appears: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use
frontend  |   ➜ Local:    http://0.0.0.0:/
frontend  |   ➜ Network:  http://172.21.0.2:/ [QR code]
frontend  |
frontend  | [nuxt:tailwindcss] ℹ Using default Tailwind CSS file
frontend  | ℹ Vite server warmed up in 43668ms
frontend  | ℹ Vite client warmed up in 52475ms
frontend  | [nitro] ✔ Nitro built in 2394 ms
frontend  | [nitro] [uncaughtException] Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use /tmp/nitro/worker-30-1.sock
frontend  |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1880:21)
frontend  |     at listenInCluster (node:net:1945:12)
frontend  |     at Server.listen (node:net:2054:5)
frontend  |     at <anonymous> (/src/node_modules/nitropack/dist/runtime/entries/nitro-dev.mjs:26:25)
frontend  |     at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
frontend  |     at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
frontend  |     at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
frontend  |     at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:113:12) {
frontend  |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
frontend  |   errno: -98,
frontend  |   syscall: 'listen',
frontend  |   address: '/tmp/nitro/worker-30-1.sock',
frontend  |   port: -1
frontend  | }


It looks like you're trying to make a request to a non-existent API route. Are you sure there's a route with that path in the server dir?

Vue Router complains about calling an external API using useFetch(). When changing the port from 80 to 3000, the errors go away, the application starts to open, but data requests from the external API do not work on the server, that is, if you go to the application page, there will be no data, but if you make several page transitions, then the data are loaded as the client repeatedly sends requests to the external API.
